# How to get the output for this code?

Tags: perl

I have a file `t_code.txt` in which I want to replace all occurrences of strings `PIOMUX_UART1_TXD` and `PIOMUX_UART1_RXD` with strings in `@array1` containing `TXD` and `RXD` respectively and then print it in new file `c_code2.txt` but it's not working

```
open my $f6, '<', 't_code.txt' or die $!;
my @lines = <$f6>;

my @newlines;
foreach (@lines) {
    $_ =~ s/PIOMUX_UART1_TXD/ grep ( / TXD / )(@array1)/g;
    $_ =~ s/PIOMUX_UART1_RXD/ grep ( / RXD / )(@array1)/g;
    push(@newlines, $_);
}

close($f6);

open my $output, '>', 'c_code2.txt' or die "Can't open the output file!";
print $output @newlines;
close($output);
```

Comment: I don't think you can simply plug grep into a string substitution. What does `@array1` look like?

Comment: @array1 contains strings in which some of them have TXD and RXD as substrings

Comment: If there is more than one element of `@rray1` that contains `TXD` then what do you want to replace `PIOMUX_UART1_TXD` with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `@array1` (a dreadful choice of identifier, by the way) doesn't change inside the loop, it is best to build the replacement strings outside instead of every time you make a replacement.

It isn't clear exactly what string you want to replace `PIOMUX_UART1_TXD` and `PIOMUX_UART1_RXD` with, but this code joins all the matching elements of the array with commas and uses that. I hope it's cler how to do something different if you need to.

I've also used a `while` loop, as there's no need to read the whole file into an array beforehand.

```
my ($in_file, $out_file) = qw/ t_code.txt c_code2.txt /;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $in_file  or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for reading: $!};
open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for writing: $!};

my ($txd) = grep /TXD/, @array1;
my ($rxd) = grep /RXD/, @array1;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
  s/PIOMUX_UART1_TXD/$txd/g;
  s/PIOMUX_UART1_RXD/$rxd/g;
  print $out_fh $_;
}

close $out_fh or die $!;
```

Comment: Its working fine for join i tried ...but in my case  there is going to be just one string containing txd and one containing rxd in array1 so i am doing                                      my $txd =  grep /TXD/, @array1;
my $rxd =  grep /RXD/, @array1;                                                                               This is  returning numeric values in $txd and $rxd somehow instead of grepped strings

Comment: @Grace90: Okay I've made a change to my solution. Give it another try.

Comment: Thanks a lot Borodin its working fine now :))  I'll really appreciate if you can let me know why was it returning numeric values and now its perfectly fine .

Comment: @Grace90: Because of point 3 from choroba's solution. `my $txd = grep ...` puts `grep` in scalar context, when it returns the *count* of the number of matching elements. Using ``my ($txd) = grep ...` applies list context instead, so `$txd` is set to the first of the list of matches that `grep` returns.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems in the code:

1. To be able to use code in the replacement part of a substitution, you must use the `/e` modifier.
2. In a `s///` construct, you can't use `/` unquoted. Either change the separator, or backslash it.
3. The replacement part in a substitution is a string. In case of code, it's evaluated in scalar context. `grep` in scalar context returns the number of matches.

Cf:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array1 = qw( aTXDb cRXDd );

while (<DATA>) {
    s/PIOMUX_UART1_TXD/join q(), grep m=TXD=, @array1/eg;
    s/PIOMUX_UART1_RXD/join q(), grep m=RXD=, @array1/eg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
PIOMUX_UART1_TXD
PIOMUX_UART1_RXD
```

Comment: i did this... open my $f6,'<','t_code.txt' or die $!;
my @lines = <$f6>; 
my @newlines;
while (<$f6>) {
    s/PIOMUX_UART1_TXD/join q(), grep m=txd=, @array1/eg;
    s/PIOMUX_UART1_RXD/join q(), grep m=rxd=, @array1/eg;
    print;
}
        close($f1);
close($f6);

Comment: open my $f6,'<','t_code.txt' or die $!;
open my $f7,'>','c_code2.txt' or die $!;
 my @lines = <$f6>;
  my @newlines; 
  while (<$f6>) 
  { 
  $_ = s/PIOMUX_UART1_TXD/join q(), grep m=txd=, @array1/eg; 
  $_ = s/PIOMUX_UART1_RXD/join q(), grep m=rxd=, @array1/eg;
   print $f7 "$_";
   } 
    close($f6);
   close($f7);

Comment: if i use the above code it gives an empty file c_code2.txt

Comment: @Grace90: Don't use the assignment operator `=` for matching, use the binding operator `=~`. Also, `$_ =~ s///` is the same as `s///`.